# How to find the information about index created on Titan/Rexster graph database with cassandra as datastore

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, rexster

I have a Rexster/Titan + Cassandra configuration. I have created unique index over vertex properties. How can I verify the index has created properly? and also to check the other properties such as uniqueness and any other information about the created index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Titan, you can use the [TitanManagement](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/current/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/schema/TitanManagement.html) API:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-berkeleydb-es.properties')
==>titangraph[berkeleyje:/home/smallette/jvm/titan-0.5.4-hadoop1/conf/../db/berkeley]
gremlin> GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g)
==>null
gremlin> mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
==>com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem@6ac756b
mgmt.getGraphIndexes(Vertex.class).collect{[it.name,it.fieldKeys.collect{it.cardinality}]}
==>[name, [SINGLE]]
==>[vertices, [SINGLE]]
gremlin> mgmt.rollback()
==>null
```

You can either issue the query as I did from the Gremlin Console or you should be able to simply issue the same query like that to Rexster's Gremlin Extension to get that result.  Be sure to call `rollback` (or `commit`) to close the management API transaction, especially if using Rexster (Rexster doesn't auto-manage those).